# Regroup low% data in a pie chart

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm struggling to find a way to group low percentage data in a specific section, for example "Others" (let's say below 1%) in a pie chart in a dynamic way (i.e. when I uncheck a data in the legend, the chart is updated automatically, so some data go back above the 1% and are not part of the others anymore.)
I work with this kind of data, and as you can see, it is not very readable and not very aesthetic:

[Pie Chart with not grouped data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDzhT.png)

But I would like something like

[Pie Chart with grouped data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IilF.png)

I already got something similar, but this was not dynamic because I was working on the data before giving it to the graph

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I didn't see **javascript** tag before working on this...
- simple approach - just prepare your data to aggregate the small slices before using **plotly**

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

# generate some data...
df = pd.DataFrame({"percent": np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(80, 100, 5), np.random.uniform(2, 20, 20)])})
df["percent"] = df["percent"] / df["percent"].sum()

# just plot as a pie,
fig = px.pie(df, values="percent")


# let's merge the small slices in the data,  plot is the same
df2 = pd.concat([df.loc[df["percent"] < 0.02].sum().to_frame().T, df.loc[df["percent"] >= 0.02]])
fig2 = px.pie(df2, values="percent")


figsp = make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=2,
    specs=[[{"type": "pie"}, {"type": "pie"}]],
    subplot_titles=["ungrouped", "grouped"],
)
figsp.add_trace(fig.data[0], row=1, col=1).add_trace(fig2.data[0], row=1, col=2)
```

[image]